# Show fingerprint again

Tags: filezilla

I have connected to my FTP server, which is configured for explicit FTP over TLS. When I connected to it for testing purposes, it showed some certificate fingerprint information.

Is it possible to show this information again while I'm connected? I know it will be displayed again when I quit Filezilla and connect again, but there's a long upload running, so I wondered if it can be seen via a menu or something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works on FileZilla 3.10.3...Connect to the site then click the lock icon in the lower right hand corner of the window.  That will display the fingerprint and other information.

Comment: Is there any way to copy Fingerprint into clipboard?

Comment: Double click on the key and the key will be in clipboard.

Comment: @krishKM: Thank you very much for that comment!!